# I get this error while installing canvas package

Tags: r, npm, canvas, package, npm-install

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c prebuild-install || npm run build-release
npm ERR! > better-sqlite3@7.5.0 build-release
npm ERR! > node-gyp rebuild --release
npm ERR! prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=17.4.0 runtime=node arch=ia32 libc= platform=win32)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.4.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.10 found at "C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/node-v17.4.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/node-v17.4.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-x64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-arm64/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-x86/node.lib
npm ERR! gyp http 404 https://\nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-arm64/node.lib#
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://\nodejs.org/download/release/v17.4.0/win-x64/node.lib#
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://\github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows#
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:122:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:75:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:363:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:71:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:384:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:406:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1090:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\Desktop\Tiga\node_modules\better-sqlite3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.4.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.4.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Thiyagarajayan.R\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-02-08T13_09_38_183Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:r]? Take a look again at [ask] to see what is needed for a question here

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?